# Smallest / Thinnest UHF/VHF Mobile Transceiver under $100

Tags: transceiver, ht, mobile, baofeng

I'm looking for the smallest/thinnest UHF or VHF two-way radio under $100. So far I've found:

- Baofeng/Pofung UV-5R (current solution)
- Baofeng/Pofung BF-888S (102m x 51mm x 11.35mm)
- [KST K-888 (122mm x 55mm x 23mm)](http://www.dhgate.com/product/new-radio-walkie-talkie-kst-k-888-uhf-400/250919228.html)
- [MINI TP-03 (86mm x 20mm x 46mm)](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/MINI-Walkie-Talkie-TP-03-Single-Frequency-Single-Band-UHF-400-470MHz-2W-16CH-Portable-Two/32379893989.html?currencyType=USD&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=708-803-3821&isdl=y&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&albcp=206813665&albag=14156629225&slnk=&trgt=56128534817&plac=&crea=en32379893989&netw=&device=c&mtctp=&gclid=CKfyjZiclcgCFUJufgodEAsGOw)

Does anyone know of a smaller/thinner radio? Any recommendation for or against a listed radio would also be appreciated.

**Note:** I haven't been able to find reliable dimensions for the BF-888S. Above are the "official" dimensions, but a YouTuber measured them to be 110mm × 50mm × **32mm**, almost three times as thick.

Answer (score 2):

The Baofeng UV-3R and UV-3R+ are both quite a bit smaller than the UV-5R or BF-888S.  The UV-3R+ uses the same programming cable as your UV-5R, if that matters to you.

Comment: Yes those are indeed smaller! Thank you! I'm really hoping for a more revolutionary answer, but so far those are the smallest radios from a recognized brand. I'd be willing to sacrifice features like the built-in speaker and LCD, both of which contribute slightly to the size of the UV-3R. Maybe I could remove them myself.

Comment: Two vendors list the UV-3R dimensions as:
210mm x 167mm x 84mm (_Amazon_) & 
**91mm × 49mm × 22mm** (_buytwowayradios.com_). Neither vendor explains how they measure.

Answer (score 2):

In some countries the Baofeng UV-82 can be found and it is preferable to the UV-5R and clones, as it has 1 extra watt output power, and it is an evolution of the UV-5R

Check this link: https://baofengtech.com/comparechart

Comment: The comparison chart you provided is very helpful. Thank you!